# Adding CSS/JS via controller magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9

Can you please let me know how to add JS/CSS via a controller method

I tried this but isn't working

```
$head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
$head->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
$head->addItem('skin_adminhtml', 'adminhtml/testimonial.css');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('jsfile.js'); //To add root js folder
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('skin_js','jsfile.js'); //To add js file under the /skin folder
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('skin_css','cssfile.css'); //To add css file under the /skin folder
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Hi Rani,  
My code is working fine as I did some mistake in config.xml block.

`$head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
$head->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
$head->addItem('skin_css', 'testimonial.css');`

But, I appreciate your help ... !!

Comment: Great  thank you